# Getting Agilent USB GBIP Adapter to work with NI-Visa or R&S GBIP over USB with Agilent Visa

Tags: measurement, test-equipment, equipment, scpi

This Visa/IVI jungle is pretty much a desaster. Not enough that each package contains GBs or data, they also cause problems when installed in parallel (one example: https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1137571).

I have the Agilent 82357B USB-GBIP adapter with which I control an E3646A supply in MATLAB. It works well with the Agilent Visa drivers.

I also have a R&S SMW200A which I control over USB with MATLAB. This works nice the NI Visa drivers.

Installing both VISA drivers makes one stop.

Is it possible to make the Agilent 82357B work with the NI drivers or the R&S SMW over USB with the Agilent drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who would think the solution is so simple.

Agilent Visa DOES seem to support the Rohde & Schwarz SMW box **via USB** (they just lead one to think one needs the NI VISA).

So kick away NI Visa, and have only Agilent/Keysight Visa installed.
In MATLAB, all that has to be done is to replace

```
visa(ni, 'USB::0x0AAD::0x0092::101165::INSTR')
```

with

```
visa('agilent', 'USB::0x0AAD::0x0092::101165::INSTR')
```